# How to approach clustering when each object does not have the same number of qualities

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering

I would like to apply a clustering algorithm to a set where each observation does not have the same number of "qualities". I have searched extensively online for this problem and were unable to find a solution or an idea on how to tackle this. This is my first stats.stackexchange post and I'm still trying to figure out how to format tables and whatnot, so my apologies for the strange look below.

The following is a dumbed down view of what my data looks like now:

`Person    | Quality
        1  | x 
        1  | y 
        2  | r 
        2  | d 
        2  | x 
        3  | y`

In other words, person 1 may have 2 conditions, or "qualities", while person 2 has 3 different conditions. I would like to group these three people into clusters, yet none of them have the same number of qualities used to describe that person. This presents a problem when attempting to apply a cluster algorithm in R. I know this is a very general question, but does anyone have experience with this kind of structure? Does there exist an algorithm that can account for this?

Comment: Is there a known finite total number of possible qualities? This sounds like clustering sparse high-dimensional categorical data.

Comment: Yes, one quality appears 54243 times, out of 46597 total people. Thus, you are right it would be clustering high-dimensional categorical data. A person on another website suggested coding 1 for "having the condition" and 0 for "not having the condition", and thus turning it into a binary matrix. However, I'm not sure an algorithm like k-means would still be appropriate, and this forces out the concept of time in the data set.

Comment: I tried to address a similar question before [here](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6322/clustering-uncertain-data-with-independent-uncertainty-per-dimension/6326#6326). See if it helps.

Comment: Clustering is *fragile*, not magic power.